# Laravel5 package view

Tags: php, laravel, package, laravel-5

I've crated package "za-web/tags"

**composer.json:**

```
{
    "name": "za-web/tags",
    "description": "",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Aleksandr Zamiatin",
            "email": "cawa123@mail.ru"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "illuminate/support": "5.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "src/views"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "ZaWeb\\Tags\\": "src/ZaWeb/Tags"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

And to view tags I'm trying to do

```
 return View::make('tags::cloud', ['data' => $data])->render();
```

And I've got the error: *No hint path defined for [tags].*

It works only if I've add to TagsServiceProvider in register() method:

```
 View::addNamespace('tags', __DIR__ . '/../../views');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution work but as explained in the [Laravel 5 documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/packages#views) on package development you should add to your ServiceProvider's boot method:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/path/to/views', 'courier');
}
```

instead of

```
 View::addNamespace('tags', __DIR__ . '/../../views');
```

If you want to publish your package views, don't forget to use the publishes method:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/path/to/views', 'courier');

    $this->publishes([
        __DIR__.'/path/to/views' => base_path('resources/views/vendor/courier'),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: L5 now supports just composer packages